# Need help setting up Python Flask framework

Tags: python, flask

I've got a XAMPP apache server, Python 2.7 and I've installed setuptools and all the Flask requirements. Still I cannot run setup.py, which generates the following error:

> You need to specify DATABASE in settings.py, and ensure that Flask-SQLAlchemy is installed.

Since I've installed Flask alchemy it must be my settings.py or something else. This is the path to my (yet to be created) database.db:

```
DATABASE = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\maraschino\maraschino.db'
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I cannot mark it as accepted, since I have not enaugh rep :) But you can find the answer below.

Comment: Thx m8 :) It says now that I can't accept my own answer in 18 hours :) I'll try again tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem already solved.

The solution is to change the 'slash' in the database path:

```
DATABASE = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\maraschino\maraschino.db'
```

must be:

```
DATABASE = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/maraschino/maraschino.db'
```

Result:

> 'Database sucessfully initialised'